# View shall Display on the Same Page after clicking a Button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I used this to display the view upon clicking this button, but the partial view doesn't display.

View:

```
<%=Ajax.ActionLink("See List", "List of Cakes", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "theList" })%>
<div id="theList"></div>
```

I added the unobtrusive script, confirmed it in web.config, what's missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out from a colleague that I do not need to check something from the web.config as the IDE will automatically add/remove added scripts.

Here are the scripts added:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```